# What does this symbol mean?

Tags: notation, rests

I've gotten a new song from my music teacher though, she never mentioned anything about this symbol.

[image: Music notation with a symbol that looks something like a "7", the symbol is marked with a circle and an arrow]

I'm rather new, can anyone explain to me what this represents?

Comment: The Elephant Song! I learned to play it when I was trying to learn Thai, and it's what I play at parties when everybody (me included) is a bit drunk. Meeting it here was an unexpected pleasure. Chaang chaang chaang!

Answer (score 11):

That's an eighth note (quaver) rest. If you know how to play the quarter note (crotchet) rest in the previous measure, then it's the same thing, just half as long.

I suggest you bookmark the following page for future reference:
[Musical symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_musical_symbols).